# Oracle Update Query using Join

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, ora-00933

I am trying to update the amount using Join but getting exception:

```
UPDATE tab1
   SET tab1.total_adjusted_cost = tab1.total_adjusted_cost + t1.total
 FROM table1 tab1, 
      (SELECT tab3.name, tab3.add, SUM(tab2.amount) AS total
         FROM table2 tab2,
              table3 tab3,
              table4 tab4
        WHERE tab2.id = tab3.id
          AND tab3.id = tab4.id
          AND tab4.indicator = 'Y'
        GROUP BY tab3.name, tab3.add ) t1
WHERE tab1.id = t1.id;


SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended 00933. 00000 -  "SQL
command not properly ended"
```

Comment: UPDATE tab1 SET tab1.total_adjusted_cost = tab1.total_adjusted_cost + t1.total
FROM table1 tab1, 
  (SELECT tab3.name, tab3.add, SUM(tab2.amount) AS total
  FROM table2 tab2,
    table3 tab3 ,
    table4 tab4
  WHERE tab2.id        = tab3.id
  AND tab3.id            = tab4.id
  AND tab4.indicator             ='Y'
  GROUP BY tab3.name,
    tab3.add
) t1
WHERE tab1.id      = t1.id

Comment: Edited Query by mistake I used group

Comment: Still It is throwing same error.

Comment: We should not use add as column name instead of add we should use "add" because it is a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use merge

```
merge into table1 tab1 
using
(
SELECT tab3.name, tab3."add", SUM(tab2.amount) AS total
  FROM table2 tab2,
    table3 tab3 ,
    table4 tab4
  WHERE tab2.id        = tab3.id
  AND tab3.id            = tab4.id
  AND tab4.indicator             ='Y'
  GROUP BY tab3.name,
    tab3."add"
)t1
on(tab1.id      = t1.id)
when matched then 
update set tab1.total_adjusted_cost = tab1.total_adjusted_cost + t1.total
```

Answer (score 0):

`group` is a keyword in sql. You have to escape it.

```
 UPDATE tab1 SET tab1.total_adjusted_cost = tab1.total_adjusted_cost + t1.total
FROM table1 tab1, 
  (SELECT tab3.name, tab3."add", SUM(tab2.amount) AS total
  FROM table2 tab2,
    table3 tab3 ,
    table4 tab4
  WHERE tab2.id        = tab3.id
  AND tab3.id            = tab4.id
  AND tab4.indicator             ='Y'
  GROUP BY tab3.name,
    tab3."add"
) t1
WHERE tab1.id      = t1.id
```

Comment: where is ti.id column

Comment: @SudhirMane can you create an sqlfiddle?

Comment: @SudhirMane also `add` is a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `select` keyword also. And follow the ANSI standard.

```
UPDATE tab1 
    SET tab1.total_adjusted_cost = (select tab1.total_adjusted_cost + t1.total
                                   FROM table1 tab1, 
                                  (SELECT tab3.name, tab3."add", SUM(tab2.amount) AS total
                                  FROM table2 tab2 JOIN  table3 tab3 
                                                    ON tab2.id   = tab3.id
                                                   JOIN  table4 tab4 
                                                    ON  tab3.id  = tab4.id
                                   WHERE tab4.indicator ='Y'
                                   GROUP BY tab3.name,tab3."add") t1
    WHERE tab1.id = t1.id);
```